# How to establish access levels using mysql for a login system based on functions?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I stagnated in a part that I am not able to understand, I would like to know how I can do to establish access levels for users working in this method, I really need an orientation, because it is very difficult.

Note: the variable $user and $pass are linked to the $_POST username and password form.

Note2: Everything is working perfectly, but I have doubts on how to be able to do access levels using the database with this code.

```
<?php
require 'AuthMeController.php';

require 'Bcrypt.php';
$authme_controller = new Bcrypt();

$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$was_successful = false;
if ($user && $pass) {
    if (isset($user) && isset($pass)) {
        $was_successful = process_login($user, $pass, $authme_controller);
    }
}

function process_login($user, $pass, AuthMeController $controller) {
    if ($controller->checkPassword($user, $pass)) {

        printf('<h1>Hello, %s!</h1>', htmlspecialchars($user));
        echo 'Successful login. Nice to have you back!<br />';
        
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['UserSession'];
        //I don't know what to do here
    
        
        //header('Location: https://mysite');
        
        echo "<br /><a href='../index.php'>Back to Form</a>";
        
        return true;
        
    } else {
        
        echo '<h1>Error</h1> Invalid username or password.';
        header('Refresh: 5; URL=https://mysite');
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is Abstract Class: AuthMeController

```
<?php
abstract class AuthMeController {

    const AUTHME_TABLE = 'authme';

     /**
     * Entry point function to check supplied credentials against the AuthMe database.
     *
     * @param string $username the username
     * @param string $password the password
     * @return bool true iff the data is correct, false otherwise
     */
    
    function checkPassword($username, $password) {
        if (is_scalar($username) && is_scalar($password)) {
            $hash = $this->getHashFromDatabase($username);
            if ($hash) {
                return $this->isValidPassword($password, $hash);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns whether the user exists in the database or not.
     *
     * @param string $username the username to check
     * @return bool true if the user exists; false otherwise
     */
    function isUserRegistered($username) {
        $mysqli = $this->getAuthmeMySqli();
        if ($mysqli !== null) {
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM ' . self::AUTHME_TABLE . ' WHERE username = ?');
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetch();
        }

        // Defensive default to true; we actually don't know
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Registers a player with the given username.
     *
     * @param string $username the username to register
     * @param string $password the password to associate to the user
     * @param string $email the email (may be empty)
     * @return bool whether or not the registration was successful
     */
    function register($username, $password, $email) {
        $email = $email ? $email : 'your@email.com';
        $mysqli = $this->getAuthmeMySqli();
        if ($mysqli !== null) {
            $hash = $this->hash($password);
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . self::AUTHME_TABLE . ' (username, realname, password, email, ip) '
                . 'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
            $username_low = strtolower($username);
            $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $username_low, $username, $hash, $email, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            return $stmt->execute();
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Changes password for player.
     *
     * @param string $username the username
     * @param string $password the password
     * @return bool true whether or not password change was successful 
     */
    function changePassword($username, $password) {
        $mysqli = $this->getAuthmeMySqli();
        if ($mysqli !== null) {
            $hash = $this->hash($password);
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE ' . self::AUTHME_TABLE . ' SET password=? '
                . 'WHERE username=?');
            $username_low = strtolower($username);
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $hash, $username_low);
            return $stmt->execute();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Hashes the given password.
     *
     * @param $password string the clear-text password to hash
     * @return string the resulting hash
     */
    protected abstract function hash($password);

    /**
     * Checks whether the given password matches the hash.
     *
     * @param $password string the clear-text password
     * @param $hash string the password hash
     * @return boolean true if the password matches, false otherwise
     */
    protected abstract function isValidPassword($password, $hash);
    
    /**
     * Returns a connection to the database.
     *
     * @return mysqli|null the mysqli object or null upon error
     */
    private function getAuthmeMySqli() {
        // CHANGE YOUR DATABASE DETAILS HERE BELOW: host, user, password, database name
        $mysqli = new mysqli('SPOILER', 'SPOILER', 'SPOILER', 'SPOILER');
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            printf('Could not connect to AuthMe database. Errno: %d, error: "%s"',
                mysqli_connect_errno(), mysqli_connect_error());
            return null;
        }
        return $mysqli;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the hash associated with the given user from the database.
     *
     * @param string $username the username whose hash should be retrieved
     * @return string|null the hash, or null if unavailable (e.g. username doesn't exist)
     */
    private function getHashFromDatabase($username) {
        $mysqli = $this->getAuthmeMySqli();
        if ($mysqli !== null) {
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT password FROM ' . self::AUTHME_TABLE . ' WHERE username = ?');
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($password);
            if ($stmt->fetch()) {
                return $password;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Bcrypt class extends AuthMeController, for Bcrypt Method hash passwords

```
<?php
class Bcrypt extends AuthMeController {

    protected function hash($password) {
        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    }

    protected function isValidPassword($password, $hash) {
        return password_verify($password, $hash);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The first step should be to extract the user role related to the logged username and keep it into the user session. A role value can be, for example, "member", "admin" etc. Session should always be started at the top of your script since if the user is not connected you could consider it "guest" role. Then you shoud have a configured ACL instance that defines what this role can do and cannot. My advice is to use Laminas ACL https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-permissions-acl/usage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a parallel file and put this file as include within the if of this function

most mistakes will probably end

thus:

```
include_once('./parallel_file.php');
```

```
function process_login($user, $pass, AuthMeController $controller) {
    if ($controller->checkPassword($user, $pass)) {

        printf('<h1>Hello, %s!</h1>', htmlspecialchars($user));
        echo 'Successful login. Nice to have you back!<br />';
        
//Put this in bellow
        include_once('./parallel_file.php');
        
        //header('Location: https://mysite');
        
        echo "<br /><a href='../index.php'>Back to Form</a>";
        
        return true;
        
    } else {
        
        echo '<h1>Error</h1> Invalid username or password.';
        header('Refresh: 5; URL=https://mysite');
    }
    return true;
}
```